# Why does my submit button look overlaid on itself in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I made a form in my PHP / jQuery Mobile web application with this HTML.

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">

    <!-- data received from a previously submitted form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="<?= $firstName ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="<?= $lastName ?>" />
    
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="favoriteWord">Favorite Word:</label>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteWord" id="favoriteWord" value="" placeholder="Please tell us your favorite word." />
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

However, my submit button looks odd. It looks overlaid on itself (as my screen shot shows).

[image]

Why?

This is the HTML I see when I do use `data-ajax="false"` (The problem still persists with ajax off) and hit "View Source".

```
<form action="/submitFavoriteWord">

    <!-- data received from a previously submitted form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="David" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="Faux" />

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="favoriteWord">Favorite Word:</label>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteWord" id="favoriteWord" value="" placeholder="Please tell us your favorite word." />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

---

Update: I analyzed the page in Chrome Web Developer. Here is what the Elements tab suggests jQuery Mobile is generating.

[image]

Strangely, there is a `<span>` tag generated above my submit button.

Comment: What does the actual source in the browser look like (not what your IDE sees).  Do a "View Source" in the browser and post the actual HTML here.

Comment: Thank you, I had just added that. Strangely, I don't see any abnormalities...

Comment: I analyzed the code in Chrome Web Developer and realized that a span tag is oddly being generated above my submit button.

Comment: That's not odd... that is injected by JQM for styling purposes.  If you take a look at the JQM examples on their page, that's how the (altered) HTML looks.  Did you edit/alter/add any CSS that's different from the JQM CSS? I have a suspicion that the ui-btn-hidden class is not really being hidden anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/FG97U/

So maybe its a problem with an unclosed HTML element somewhere else on the page?  This can be verified if you post more of your code, but I have seen this happen and checking the other HTML on the page may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had loaded two entire web pages into one (so there were two blocks of `html` tags).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely un-closed tag or extra fieldcontainer